# If a switch has one condition, but several cases to check that condition, does it execute remaining cases IF the condition is met in the first case?

Tags: javascript

Does the switch execute the remaining cases IF today's date is Sunday and there are no other conditions?

```
switch (new Date().getDay()) {
 case 0:
   day = "Sunday";
   break;
 case 1:
   day = "Monday";
   break;
 case 2:
   day = "Tuesday";
   break;
 case 3:
   day = "Wednesday";
   break;
 case 4:
   day = "Thursday";
   break;
 case 5:
   day = "Friday";
   break;
 case 6:
   day = "Saturday";
}
```

Comment: if you remove the break; statement then either first condition is matched or not, all cases will be checked

Comment: That's the whole point (or main point, or something) of `switch` `case` and `break`.
Specifically for your code, you don't have to use `switch`.  use:
`day=["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"][new Date().getDay()]`.

Comment: Thanks...that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

No it won't check the other conditionals because you have a break statement after going into the condition. The break will exit the switch statement all together.

Comment: Thanks, got it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

since you already put `break;` on each case it will stop executing after the correct case executed

Answer (score 0):

No the `break` prevent that But still "Saturday" requires more time than "Sunday"

However you can simplify the code using the day number to lookup the day name meaning you don't need any conditions, less code, and much quicker

```
// Do once 
const DAY_NAMES = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
```

In function replace you switch with.

```
 day = DAY_NAMES[new Date().getDay()];
```

Comment: Almost identical to my comment! :)

Comment: @iAmOren Sorry did not see your comment. Warning about string arrays. String are immutable

Comment: It's all good.
Please elaborate: where did I try to mutate a String?

Comment: @iAmOren  the array and each string item will be instantiated each time you use it. A lot of overhead that can be avoided if declared once.

Comment: I see.
Well, we don't know that it will be used more than once.
In case it will be used more than once - Storing it in some variable (const?) would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks everyone for responding.